# How do you initialize and add data to variable of "[][]" in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xsd

I generated a new C# class from a XML file using xsd.exe:

```
test.xml
--------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output>
   <ReportType name="New Reports">
      <Reports>
         <Report name="report1">
            <Items>
               <Item name="item1">
                  <Value>1.00</Value>
               </Item>
               <Item name="item2">
                  <Value>2.00</Value>
               </Item>
            </Items>
         </Report>
         <Report name="report2">
            <Items>
               <Item name="item3">
                  <Value>3.00</Value>
               </Item>
               <Item name="item4">
                  <Value>4.00</Value>
               </Item>
            </Items>
         </Report>
      </Reports>
   </ReportType>
</Output>
```

[You can see the C# class it generates here.](http://www.codesend.com/view/f4890aa6b83f551409de415b3ed5f55a/)

Now I am trying to leverage the generated class to produce a new xml file and I need to set this variable:

```
private OutputReportTypeReportsReport[][] reportsField;
```

How do I initialize and add data to it?

Comment: That is called a `Jagged Array` your can learn more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
OutputReportTypeReportsReport[][] reportsField = new OutputReportTypeReportsReport[100][];
reportsField [0] = new OutputReportTypeReportsReport[1] { object1 };
reportsField [1] = new OutputReportTypeReportsReport[2] { object2, object3 };
...
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx